# Mandelbrot Conversion

Tags: c#

I'm receiving no errors but when I'm running it I'm also unable to see the Mandelbrot it just displays the grey box, I'm currently stuck at this one point thanks for any help, if you see any other parts of my code which contains grammar or coding errors it would be much appreciated if you told me.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;    

namespace SE_Fractal_Assignment
{    
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {    
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();    
        }

        public struct HSBColor
        {
            float h;
            float s;
            float b;
            int a;

            public HSBColor(float h, float s, float b)
            {
                this.a = 0xff;
                this.h = Math.Min(Math.Max(h, 0), 255);
                this.s = Math.Min(Math.Max(h, 0), 255);
                this.b = Math.Min(Math.Max(h, 0), 255);
            }

            public float H
            {
                get { return h; }
            }

            public float S
            {
                get { return s; }
            }

            public float B
            {
                get { return b; }
            }

            public int A
            {
                get { return a; }
            }

            public Color Color
            {
                get
                {
                    return FromHSB(this);
                }
            }

            public static Color FromHSB(HSBColor hsbColor)
            {
                float r = hsbColor.b;
                float g = hsbColor.b;
                float b = hsbColor.b;
                if (hsbColor.s != 0)
                {
                    float max = hsbColor.b;
                    float dif = hsbColor.b * hsbColor.s / 255f;
                    float min = hsbColor.b - dif;
                    float h = hsbColor.h * 360f / 255f;

                    if (h < 60f)
                    {
                        r = max;
                        g = h * dif / 60f + min;
                        b = min;
                    }
                    else if (h < 120f)
                    {
                        r = -(h - 120f) * dif / 60f + min;
                        g = max;
                        b = min;
                    }
                    else if (h < 180f)
                    {
                        r = min;
                        g = max;
                        b = -(h - 120f) * dif / 60f + min;
                    }
                    else if (h < 240f)
                    {
                        r = min;
                        g = -(h - 240f) * dif / 60f + min;
                        b = max;
                    }
                    else if (h < 300f)
                    {
                        r = -(h - 240f) * dif / 60f + min;
                        g = min;
                        b = max;
                    }
                    else if (h <= 360f)
                    {
                        r = max;
                        g = min;
                        b = -(h - 360f) * dif / 60f + min;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        r = 0;
                        g = 0;
                        b = 0;
                    }
                }

                return Color.FromArgb
                (
                    hsbColor.a,
                    (int)Math.Round(Math.Min(Math.Max(r, 0), 255)),
                    (int)Math.Round(Math.Min(Math.Max(g, 0), 255)),
                    (int)Math.Round(Math.Min(Math.Max(b, 0), 255))
                    );
            }
        }

        private const int MAX = 256;         // max iterations
        private const double SX = -2.025;    // start value goal
        private const double SY = -1.125;    // start value imaginary
        private const double EX = 0.6;       // end value real
        private const double EY = 1.125;     // end value imaginary
        private static int x1, y1, xs, ys, xe, ye;
        private static double xstart, ystart, xende, yende, xzoom, yzoom;
        private static bool action, rectangle, finished;
        private static float xy;
        //private Image picture1;
        private System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap;
        private Graphics g1;
        private Cursor c1, c2;
        private HSBColor HSBcol = new HSBColor();
        // private HSB HSBcol = new HSB();

        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            g1 = e.Graphics;
            g1.DrawImage(bitmap, 0, 0, x1, y1);
            g1.Dispose();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            init();
            start();
        }

        public void init()
        {
            //HSBcol = new HSB();
            finished = false;
            c1 = Cursors.WaitCursor;
            c2 = Cursors.Cross;

            x1 = 640;
            y1 = 480;

            xy = (float)x1 / (float)y1;

            bitmap.SetPixel(x1, y1, Color.Blue);
            g1 = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);

            finished = true;

            // xy = (float)x1 / (float)y1;
            //picture = createImage(x1, y1); 
            //g1 = picture.getGraphics();
        }

        public void destroy() // delete all instances 
        {
            if (finished)
            {
                //removeMouseListener(this);
                //removeMouseMotionListener(this);
                //bitmap = null;

                g1 = null;
                c1 = null;
                c2 = null;

                //System.gc(); // garbage collection
                GC.Collect();
            }
        }

        public void start()
        {
            action = false;
            rectangle = false;

            initvalues();

            xzoom = (xende - xstart) / (double)x1;
            yzoom = (yende - ystart) / (double)y1;
            mandelbrot();
        }

        public void stop()
        {
        }

        public void paint(Graphics g)
        {
            update(g); 
        }

        public void update(Graphics g)
        {  
            /*  Pen myPen = new Pen(Color.White);
            g.DrawImage(bitmap, 0, 0);
            if (rectangle)
            {
                if (xs < xe)
                {
                    if (ys < ye)
                    {
                        g.DrawRectangle(myPen, xs, ys, (xe - xs), (ye - ys));
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    g.DrawRectangle(myPen, xs, ys, (xe - xs), (ye - ys));
                }
                myPen.Dispose();
            }*/
        }

        private void mandelbrot() // calculate all points
        {
            int x, y;
            float h, b, alt = 0.0f;

            action = false;
            for (x = 0; x < x1; x += 2)
                for (y = 0; y < y1; y++)
                {
                    h = pointcolour(xstart + xzoom * (double)x, ystart + yzoom * (double)y);
                    // color value

                    if (h != alt)
                    {
                        b = 1.0f - h * h; // brightnes

                        ///djm added

                        ///HSBcol.fromHSB(h,0.8f,b); 
                        ///
                        //convert hsb to rgb then make a Java Color

                        Color color = HSBColor.FromHSB(new HSBColor(h * 255, 0.8f * 255, b * 255));

                        ///g1.setColor(col);
                        //djm end
                        //djm added to convert to RGB from HSB

                        //g1.setColor(Color.getHSBColor(h, 0.8f, b));
                        //djm test

                        //  Color col = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0);

                        //red = Color.Red;
                        // green = Color.Green;
                        // blue = Color.Blue;

                        //djm 
                        alt = h;
                    }
                    Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Aqua);
                    g1.DrawLine(pen, x, y, x + 1, y);
                }
                //showStatus("Mandelbrot-Set ready - please select zoom area with pressed mouse.");
                //setCursor(c2);
                action = true;
            }

            private float pointcolour(double xwert, double ywert)
            // color value from 0.0 to 1.0 by iterations
            {
                double r = 0.0, i = 0.0, m = 0.0;
                int j = 0;

                while ((j < MAX) && (m < 4.0))
                {
                    j++;
                    m = r * r - i * i;
                    i = 2.0 * r * i + ywert;
                    r = m + xwert;
                }
                return (float)j / (float)MAX;
            }

            private void initvalues() // reset start values
            {
                xstart = SX;
                ystart = SY;
                xende = EX;
                yende = EY;
                if ((float)((xende - xstart) / (yende - ystart)) != xy)
                    xstart = xende - (yende - ystart) * (double)xy;
            }


            private void Form1_paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
            {
                Graphics g = e.Graphics;

                g1 = g;
                action = false;
                rectangle = false;
                initvalues();
                xzoom = (xende - xstart) / (double)x1;
                yzoom = (yende - ystart) / (double)y1;

                //picture = g.DrawImage;

                //g.DrawImage(picture,0,0);
                update(g);
                mandelbrot();
            }

            private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
            {
                if (action)
                {
                    xs = e.X;
                    ys = e.Y;
                }
            }

            private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
            {
                // e.consume();
                if (action)
                {
                    xe = e.X;
                    ye = e.Y;
                    rectangle = true;
                    //repaint();
                }
            }

            private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
            {
                rectangle = false;
            }

            private void Form1_Click(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
            {

            }

            public String getAppletInfo()
            {
                return "fractal.class - Mandelbrot Set a Java Applet by Eckhard Roessel 2000-2001";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The basic etiquette for SO dictates that you should not put tags in your title. http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging

Comment: A newbie might want to take the opportunity to learn how to more effectively use the site.

Comment: it's hard to see on first glance but usually I start doing this stuff by just outputting monochrome images (white for *escaped* points - ie outside the set, and black for outside) - this should give you a hint if your algorithm works - if not check points like (0,0) and (1.5,0) - one should iter forever the other should escape

Comment: @BoBBob123 I was not intending to "rip" on you, just to let you know.  Sorry if I came across that way.

Comment: `rather than helping him out with his actual problem` Maybe you want to narrow down the problem and post a smaller code. I, for example, am not willing to read all of it.

Comment: @BoBBob123 just ignore the noise around here - C# tagged questions can be quite rude

Comment: the way you set up your question makes it **very** difficult to answer - if you want you can put your project on github and share the link here - then I will have a look, but I will not setup a project, copy&paste/guess your code and then debug it - sorry

Comment: the alternative is that *you* try to find the parts that causes your problems and ask about this

Comment: @CarstenKonig i'm very new to C# and i don't really understand what your asking me to do could you dumb it down a little for me thanks

Comment: @L.B me posting smaller code would not solve anything as like i stated I'm not receiving any errors so its hard to narrow it down the problem I'm having is just it isn't displaying the end goal which is the Mandelbrot

Comment: is the formula you use to calculate the sequence of complex points inside `pointcolour`? - If yes then you only check the real part `< 4` but you should check `|z|² = re(z)² + im(z)² = r*r + i*i`

Comment: @BoBBob123 please stop the useless quarrel and have a look at your `pointcolour` - does this solve your issue?

Comment: @carstenKonig as far as i know the formula is all correct where i think the problem could be is my "private System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap" as im receiving the warning   Warning 2 Field 'SE_Fractal_Assignment.Form1.bitmap' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null F:\SoftwareEngineering\Fractal Assignment\SE Fractal Assignment\SE Fractal Assignment\Form1.cs 155 43 SE Fractal Assignment

Comment: @BoBBob123 I'm rather sure your formula is not correct - you use `m` to check the bounds but `m` is more or less just the real-part of the squared predecessor but you want the abs. or the square of the abs. of the comlex number

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, the code is so cluttered and disorganized, it's hard to know all of what might be wrong with it. Sorry to be so blunt.

That said, a couple of obvious problems I see involving your "g1" Graphics instance member.

First, you are using the same field for two purposes: when computing the original image, you expect this to be a Graphics instance you can use to draw into your bitmap. But in the Paint event, you set it to the Graphics instance for the window, into which the painting should be done.

Second, in that Paint event, you dispose the Graphics instance before you return. But the instance you're disposing isn't yours. It belongs to the Forms system, and the only thing you should be doing with it is drawing into it.

There actually appear to be two different Paint event handlers and it's not clear which one you're using. You only dispose the Graphics instance in one of those places, so that may or may not be the real problem.

Personally, I would break the problem down into different elements. For a relative novice, it can be hard enough just to correctly draw a bitmap. It can also be difficult to really grasp how Paint event handling should be done. And of course, there's the Mandelbrot computations themselves. Trying to implement all three things (and more) at the same time can be overwhelming, and will take a lot longer assuming you can figure it out at all.

I would start by writing a simple program that just has a single PictureBox, which when you click a button, your program creates a new Bitmap object, into which you draw something simple (say, a rectangle, circle, or maybe just some text) and then assigns that Bitmap object to the PictureBox.Image property.

Once you have that working, then you can change the drawing part of the code to draw a Mandelbrot image instead.

Finally, once you have that working, then you can work on using the Paint event to draw the bitmap into your window directly instead of using the PictureBox control (the main reason for wanting to do this would presumably be that you eventually want to update the image as it's being drawn...if you only want to show it at the very end, then IMHO the PictureBox is a better approach).

Comment: +1 http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/give_a_man_a_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_day;_teach_a_man_to_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_lifetime